# passing 2d array of pointers to function giving error

Tags: c, pointers

So I am passing a 3 by 3 array of float points.  The function foo will allocate memory for each pointer.  Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(float ***A);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    float* A[3][3];
    foo(&A);
}

void foo(float ***A) {
   int i,j;
   for(i=0;i<3;i++){
      for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        A[i][j] = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
        A[i][j][0] = 21;
      }
   }
}
```

Why does this does not work?  It throws the following error:

```
C:\Users\tony\Code\MPI>gcc test.c
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:8: warning: passing argument 1 of 'foo' from incompatible pointer type
test.c:4: note: expected 'float ***' but argument is of type 'float *** (*)[3][3]'
```

So If I call foo(A) instead of foo(&A) I get this error instead:

```
C:\Users\tony\Code\MPI>gcc test.c
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:8: warning: passing argument 1 of 'foo' from incompatible pointer type
test.c:4: note: expected 'float ***' but argument is of type 'float * (*)[3]'
```

Comment: `typeof` should be `sizeof`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(float *(*A)[3][3]);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    float* A[3][3];
    foo(&A);
    return 0;
}

void foo(float *(*A)[3][3]) {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            (*A)[i][j] = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
            (*A)[i][j][0] = 21;
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you does not want to change the value of a variable itself in a function, you does not need to pass the address of that variable to this function. Therefore, this simpler version also works in this case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(float *A[3][3]);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    float* A[3][3];
    foo(A);
    return 0;
}

void foo(float *A[3][3]) {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            A[i][j] = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
            A[i][j][0] = 21;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why pass the address of `A` and complicate it?

Comment: I agree with @Rik. Just declare `void foo( float *A[3][3] );` and call `foo(A);`

Comment: isn't `*A[3][3]` the same as `***A`?  I'm confused why these are different.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay Because the original post tries to do it, so I just demonstrate how to do it correctly. But yes, it is unnecessary.

Comment: @anthonybell No, it is not. Simply, array cannot always be treated like a pointer.

Comment: @anthonybell No. Not when `A` is a multidimensional array. Multidimensional arrays are stored in contiguous memory locations. So you need to specify the dimensions. In general for an `n` dimensional array, specifying the last `n-1` dimensions is enough. The first one then can be predicted. See the article about row major and column major matrices in Wikipedia.

Comment: so `void foo(float *A[3][3])` works but does this mean I have to know the dimensions at compile-time then?

Comment: @anthonybell If you are declaring the matrix, you know the dimensions. But if you are dynamically allocating it, you can pass it as `void foo(float ***)`.

Comment: @leeduhem A +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing a two-dimensional array to a function:

```
int labels[NROWS][NCOLUMNS];
f(labels);
```

the function's declaration must match:

```
void f(int labels[][NCOLUMNS])
{ ... }
```

or

```
void f(int (*ap)[NCOLUMNS]) /* ap is a pointer to an array */
{ ... }
```

Comment: Isn't `void f(int **ap)` equivalent to `void f(int ap[][])`?

Comment: No the important distinction is that the declaration includes the number of columns, for example in the declaration `void f(int array[][3]);` the number `3` is extremely important.  The reason is that the compiler needs that number to compute the address of an element.  For example, to locate `array[2][1]` the compiler computes the address as follows `address = array_base_address + ((2 * 3) + 1) * sizeof(array_element_type))`.  Without knowing the number of columns in the array, that address calculation is not possible.

Comment: @user3386109 Here the pointer declaration is explicit and the called function doesn't allocate memory for the array which does not need to know the overall size leaving rows back.

Answer (score 1):

`float* A[3][3];` is a 2D array of pointers.

But you are passing address of A and receiving it as `float ***`. So the error.

Pass it as `foo(A);` and change function prototype as

```
void foo(float* A[][3]);
```

Also, `typeof` should be `sizeof`.

```
A[i][j] = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
```